# Reverting multiple rotations of an (irrational) angle

Tags: geometry, complex-numbers

### Problem

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ , $|a|=1$ and $c\in\mathbb{R}$. 
Let us assume that $\exists{n\in\mathbb{N}} \;\; a=\exp(c i n)$

Find the value of smallest possible $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

### Background

I am working on a computer program where the value of $a$ is generated by substituting some $n$ into the expression. Now I would like to revert the process and find out what was the value of $n$ when I am given only $a$ itself, or actually its floating representation .

Comment: The mathematical question you have asked is totally different from the programming problem you want to solve, since in the programming problem you are only representing the numbers to some finite level of accuracy and presumably you only want $a=\exp(cin)$ to hold approximately.

Comment: @EricWofsey, the programming problem, I believe, concerns the case where $c\in\mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $c\neq 0.$
Since $a=e^{i\theta},$ we are looking for $n$ satisfying $\;{cn}={\theta}.$ If such $n$ exists, then any $$n+\frac{2\pi k}{c},\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$ satisfies, as $$e^{ic(n+2\pi k/c)}=e^{icn}=e^{i\theta}=a.$$

Comment: That is a right observation, thank you.  

One could use it to find out the $n$, by taking $n_*=\frac{\log{a}}{ci}$,  evaluating expression $n_*+ \frac{2\pi k}{c}$ for different values of $k$, and looking for the values that are integers.  

It is not a satisfying solution since it is not any better than just guessing $n$.